# ArrayPlot of square matrix: how does ColorFunction -> Automatic work?

Tags: plotting, graphics, color

Suppose you have the following:

```
tt = Table[{i, j}, {i, 0, 10}, {j, 0, 10}]
```

The table `tt` is a matrix of pairs, `{i, j}`.  Now you issue

```
ArrayPlot[tt]
```

you get a nice image with the top row and the rightmost column white.

How does `ArrayPlot` work in this case?  I tried to look into the `ColorFunction` documentation but I was not able to actually understand how the system is working.  I am curious to find an explanation.

Answer (score 1):

In this case `GrayLevel[g,a]` is used where `a` is the alpha-value. You can see this easily by drawing a rectangle below your plot:

```
tt = Table[{i, j}, {i, 0, 10}, {j, 0, 10}];
Show[Graphics[{Red, Rectangle[{0, 0}, {11, 11}]}],
  ArrayPlot[tt]
]
```

> [image: Mathematica graphics]

As suggested by Kuba here an additional example:

```
Row[{ArrayPlot[tt], ArrayPlot[tt, ColorFunction -> (GrayLevel[1-#] &)]}]
```

> [image: Mathematica graphics]

And finally, `ArrayPlot` creates a [`Raster`](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/Raster.html) and this information can be found  under Scope -> Raster Styling section.

Comment: Thanks.  That was very helpful.  Took me a bit more, but I think I grokked it.  There should be a bit more of explanation directly in the ArrayPlot documentation.